# C++: Long delay on cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload after upgrade to GTX970

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, gpu

I have been using the gpu module (cuda) of OpenCV in my program for a while and it worked fine. Now I upgraded my graphics card to a gtx970. Now, the first time I call cv::gpu::GpuMat::upload after launching the program I get a very long delay. With my old graphics card (GTX770) this completed nearly instantly.

Example: I have an image which is 512x600 pixels in size. With this image it takes 12s. If I execute the same code again afterwards without closing the program it works instantaneously. I know that the first time the CUDA code is executed after launching the program, it is compiled on the GPU, so a certain delay is normal. But to me this appears to be inexplicably long, especially because it was much faster with the old card.

Does anyone know what could cause this behaviour? Are there any known issues of the current OpenCV version in connection with GTX970 cards? The version I am using is 2.4.10 which is, apart from the 3.0beta, the latest one.

I now also discovered that there is a Release of the CUDA Toolkit that specifically supports GTX970 and GTX980 cards:

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-dow...

I downloaded it and compiled OpenCV again with that one. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. Somehow I have got the feeling it takes even longer now.

Is there anyone here who has any experiences with GTX900 cards and OpenCV?

This is the code, if anyone wants to see it:

```
    if (_cudaAvailable){
        try{
            _gpuUploadMutex.lock();
            //upload image channels to the gpu if using cuda
            cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuMat;
            gpuMat.upload(_originalImage);
            cv::gpu::split(gpuMat, _originalImageChannelsCuda);
            _gpuUploadMutex.unlock();
            std::cout << "Image uploaded to GPU successfully" << std::endl;
        }
        catch (...){
            std::cerr << "Error occured while using CUDA, falling back to CPU. (Insufficient video RAM?)" << std::endl;
            _cudaAvailable = false;
            _gpuUploadMutex.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Nothing special. The line of code that is causing the initial delay is the gpuMat.upload.

Comment: Did you compile openCV yourself to get the cuda library support? Did you recompile openCV? Do both graphics cards support different architectures?

Comment: If you upload a second image (not the same one) is there another delay?

Comment: It sounds like you are hitting JIT-compile delays.  Even the new toolkit won't fix it if you don't recompile with the necessary switches (`-arch=sm_52`) for your shiny new Maxwell.

Comment: 1st: Yes, I compiled openCV myself
2nd: No, afterwards I can upload any image without delay
3rd: Thanks for the tip. Where can I set this swtich? cmake? Or do I have to set this as a compiler flag when compiling opencv?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/cuda/doc/introduction.html "NVIDIA* compiler enables generating binary code (cubin and fatbin) and intermediate code (PTX). Binary code often implies a specific GPU architecture and generation, so the compatibility with other GPUs is not guaranteed." [...] "For platforms where JIT compilation is performed first, the run is slow"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your program tries to execute code on a GPU the driver will check the executable for suitable code to run on your specific GPU. The executable is known as a "fat binary", meaning it can contain code for multiple architectures.

In the case of GPUs, the executable can contain machine code for different GPUs as well as PTX, which is a slightly higher level language (looks like assembly) which can be compiled at runtime to the specific GPU.

In your case I would guess that the binary contains machine code for the original GPU (GTX770 is compute capability 3.0) but not for the new GPU (GTX970 is compute capability 5.2). So when you run on the new GPU the driver finds the PTX (also included in the fat binary) and recompiles it to sm5.2. This recompilation is taking the time.

If you can find your compilation command you'll see something like this:

```
nvcc ... -gencode arch=compute_30,code=\'compute_30,sm_30\'
```

which you should change to:

```
nvcc ... -gencode arch=compute_30,code=\'compute_30,sm_30,sm_52\'
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for this information! I have a visual studio project of OpenCV generated with cmake. Unfortunately I have no idea where the cuda compiler is actually called and where I should add this flag. I am admittedly not really an expert on this.

Comment: This is what the project looks like: http://i.imgur.com/TWdfd4y.png Those compiler options are, I guess, for the Visual Studio compiler.

Comment: I think you have to compile openCV for that new architecture but thats just a guess.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: When generating the OpenCV project files with cmake there is a variable `CUDA_ARCH_BIN` in the `CUDA` group that was set to the value `1.1 1.2 1.3 2.0 2.1(2.0) 3.0 3.5`. I appended `5.2` to the list, generated and then compiled again, and now it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @bweber, no. You do not append. You should simply replace.